# Source for not whistling at night?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, evening-night

I have heard that one is not allowed to whistle at night, something to do with bringing demons.
does anyone know a source for this?

Comment: overlaps with https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/722/170

Comment: א ייד פייף נישט